# How we can receive data(json) based on the previous choice?

Tags: java, php, android, mysqli

We have an application for showing cars' information.
We have couple of brands (for instance BMW, AUDI, etc.)  in the first page of the application that if you click on them, a list of that brand's cars (the cars which belongs to that clicked brand) will open and then if you click on each of those cars, a list of the car's information will open; for example, "how we can use this car?" if you click on this, you will see a video or pdf file in the next page that help you to reach what you asked.
We've made separate tables for each of these parts and they have unique IDs.
In the Android side:
How we can receive data based on the previous choice? (I mean, for example if the client
click on the BMW brand, they can see a list contains (for example) BMW X7, BMW M3, gran coupe, etc.)
we've set "Buttons" for brands in the first page and in the cars' page too, but in other pages we've set "recycler view".
how we can show "wanted information" based on received data?

The main problem is that we do not know whether we need to change Json or change Android programing.
Or is the best way to send a request for each page to an api?

Answer (score 0):

read more about adapter calss 
it will solve your problem